# How can I specify a column for a variable in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: jinja2, ansible-template

I have a jinja2 template that looks like this.

```
{% for file in result['files'] %}
descriptiontxt        {{ inventory_hostname }}{{ file['path'] | truncate(50)}} {{ {{ '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S' | strftime(file['lastwritetime']) }} MoreDescriptiveText
```

In this example, the output might look like this.

```
descriptiontxt        host1C:\dir\directory\directory\directory\txt.txt 20210106T081330 MoreDescriptiveText
descriptiontxt        host2C:\dir\directory\txt.txt 20210106T081330 MoreDescriptiveText
descriptiontxt        host3C:\dir\directory\truncated\example\123456677 20210106T081330 MoreDescriptiveText
```

I want the output to look like this.

```
descriptiontxt        host1C:\dir\directory\directory\directory\txt.txt 20210106T081330 MoreDescriptiveText
descriptiontxt        host2C:\dir\directory\txt.txt                     20210106T081330 MoreDescriptiveText
descriptiontxt        host3C:\dir\directory\truncated\example\123456677 20210106T081330 MoreDescriptiveText
```

How can I make sure that the date string starts on column 72 (or some other position) for every line of the file?
Regardless of whether the previous entry is 10 characters or 50 characters, given that truncate on the previous variable ensures that the path variable never overflows into that portion of the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by using the `format` filter, like this:

```
{% for file in result['files'] %}
descriptiontxt        {{ inventory_hostname }}{{ "%-50s"|format(file['path'] | truncate(50))}} {{ {{ '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S' | strftime(file['lastwritetime']) }} MoreDescriptiveText
{% endfor %}
```

This ensure that `file['path']` takes up 50 characters even if the actual string is shorter.